# How to check if user has completed video in AdMob for Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I am using AdMob rewarded videos in my Unity Game. I have two questions:

1. Documentation states that you need to set up mediation networks, I have not set up any and still get ads. How is that?
2. How do I detect if the user has completed the video? There are not any methods which fire only if the video has completed.

Comment: Could you link the API reference of the method you use in 2.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got Rewarded Video Ads from another network, and not just built-in Admob ads?

The answer to the second question can be found in [the Firebase documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/rewarded-video).

Basically you create a RewardBasedVideoAd instance and attach an OnAdRewarded event handler to it:

```
private void RequestRewardBasedVideo(){
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       string adUnitId = "unused";
   #elif UNITY_ANDROID
       string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
   #elif UNITY_IPHONE
       string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
   #else
       string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
   #endif

   RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

   AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
   rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
}
```

...

```
// Reward based video instance is a singleton. Register handlers once to
// avoid duplicate events.
if (!rewardBasedEventHandlersSet){
   // Ad event fired when the rewarded video ad
   // has been received.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
   // has failed to load.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
   // is opened.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
   // has started playing.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
   // has rewarded the user.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
   // is closed.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
   // is leaving the application.
   rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;

   rewardBasedEventHandlersSet = true;
}
```

...

```
public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args){
   string type = args.Type;
   double amount = args.Amount;
   print("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to integrate Admob Rewarded Video](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob#8how-to-integrate-admob-rewarded-video-to-unity3d-app) to Unity3d app?
Here is the minimal code to create an admob video.

```
Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

Simular with interstitial,video need to be explicitly shown at an appropriate stopping point in your app, check that the video is ready before showing it:

```
if (Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
  Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
}
```

handle video event

```
Admob.Instance().onRewardedVideoStarted += myRewardedVideoStartedFun ;
Admob.Instance().onRewarded += myRewardedFun ;
```